# Why does my "while" loop execute no matter what i enter?

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

```
/*********************************************************
** Purpose: Asks the user for cable package they bought **
** and the amount of hrs they used and //tells them     **
** their monthly bill                                   **
**********************************************************/                                        




#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //Defining variables
    double hours_over;  //Amount of hrs the user went over their monthly allottment
    double extra_pay;   //Extra bill amount for going over monthly hrs allotted
    double monthly_bill;  //Monthly bill the user will pay
    int hours;          // How many hours the user used during the month
    char package;       //The package the user chose

    //Getting the package the user bought
    cout << "Your monthly subscription bill is based on your package.";
    cout << "\n\nWhat package did you buy? Enter A, B or C: ";
    cin >> package;

    //Validating user input-must enter A, B or C
    while (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C')
    {
      cout << "\nPlease enter A, B or C(capitalized).";
      cout << "\n\nWhat package did you buy?: ";
      cin >> package;
    }

    //Getting hours the user used during month
    cout << "How many hours did you use?: ";
    cin >> hours;

    //Validating user input-hrs cant exceed 744
    while (hours > 744)
    {
      cout << "I'm sorry but your monthly usage cannot exceed 744 hrs.";
      cout << "\nPlease enter another number.";
      cout << "How many hours did you use?: ";
      cin >> hours;
    }

    //Fixing decimal place of answers
    cout << setprecision(2) << fixed << showpoint << endl;

    //Switch statement-go to the package the user bought
    switch (package)
    {
       case 'A':
            if (hours > 10)
            {
                      hours_over=hours-10;
                      extra_pay=hours_over*(2.00);
                      monthly_bill=9.95+extra_pay;

                      cout << "Your monthly bill is: $" << monthly_bill << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                 cout << "Your monthly bill is: $9.95";
            }
            break;

       case 'B':
            if (hours > 20)
            {
                      hours_over=hours-20;
                      extra_pay=hours_over;
                      monthly_bill=14.95+extra_pay;

                      cout << "Your monthly bill is: $" << monthly_bill << endl;
            }
            else
            {
                 cout << "Your monthly bill is: $14.95";
            }
            break;

       case 'C':
            cout << "Your monthly bill is: $19.95";
            break;

       default:
            break;   
    }

cin.get();
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Did you use a debugger? What have you tried? Also, if you're asking about a particular snippet of code, there's no reason to copy/paste an entire program. People are less willing to help when they have to stare at a huge wall of code with no further context from you.

Comment: im sorry....my bad, its the 1st while loop, look at that. Thats where the code keeps repeating

Comment: yeah i shouldnt have pasted the entire code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your test for A, B, or C is wrong

```
 while (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C')
```

should be

```
 while (package != 'A' && package != 'B' && package != 'C')
```

Comment: Also, the user could still enter an invalid package on the second try.  Both inputs should use similar while loops.

Comment: ok...this is correct.....ok i need to put && in there...duh @_@..........im new to all this

Comment: @Theran: It seems the code was sneakily changed to use a "while" instead of an "if" here (so my post and your comment don't make as much sense). Changing my post to include the new "while"

Comment: yeah it was originally supposed to be a "while", i typed it wrong, so i changed it back to what it was supposed to be...sorry for the confusion. but this answer is right, its fixed now..........thanks

Answer (score 2):

Consider your expression:

```
while (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C') {
```

Let package have the value 'A'.

This evaluates to

```
false || true || true
```

which is of course true.

Answer (score 1):

This line always evaluates to true:

```
while (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C')
```

it should probably be:

```
while (package != 'A' && package != 'B' && package != 'C')
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be checking to see if cin has been able to stream a value of the desired type, ala `if (cin >> my_int)`, then using `std::cin.clear()` after an erroneous input before getting them to reenter the value.  Otherwise, garbage values like say some text input that can't be converted to an int leave `std::cin` in an error state and the next `std::cin >> xxx` isn't even attempted.

Answer (score 0):

The "while" will only loop when you want it to, but the "if" will always fire; is that what you mean? The "if" concerning A, B, or C always fires because you've used "||" meaning "or" to link conditions. It is always true, for any value of your variable, that it's not A, or not B, or not C!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, this code:

```
//Validating user input-must enter A, B or C
if (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C')
{
  cout << "\nPlease enter A, B or C(capitalized).";
  cout << "\n\nWhat package did you buy?: ";
  cin >> package;
}
```

won't work, because (1) you're comparing a string (package) to characters, and (2) you're using || (or) instead of && (and).  Also (3) you probably want "while" instead of "if".

The while loop worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
cin >> package;
//Validating user input-must enter A, B or C
while (package != 'A' || package != 'B' || package != 'C')
{
  cout << "\nPlease enter A, B or C(capitalized).";
  cout << "\n\nWhat package did you buy?: ";
  cin >> package;
}
```

What if the `package` value is **B** entered inside the loop. It satisfies the first condition `package != 'A'` and since it is an **OR** operation after it( **true || false || true** leads to **true**), loop enters. You should use `&&` instead. So, change

```
 while (package != 'A' && package != 'B' && package != 'C')
 {
     // .....
 }
```